# Make multiple string variables same length c#

Tags: c#, string, string-length

I have to make a method that exports database data to a file. The software that will process this file requires specific string length - no more, no less. The data that comes in will have less than the required number of characters, but I have to make the length of every column fit that number exactly by addind whitespaces.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this in the most efficient way? The datasets won't be small and the only thing that comes to mind is looping over every table cell, checking the length and then adding up to the required length...

Comment: Have look at `String.PadLeft` and `String.PadRight`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36f2hz3a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: _"how to do this in the most efficient way?"_ It really depends on how you're getting the data out and passing it across to the file etc.  Ideally you'd want to do this in some sort of streaming fashion, without allocating a bunch of new strings.

Comment: Can you tag your DBMS? That would probably be the most efficient place to introduce the padding (in your query).

Comment: @JamesThorpe streaming to file directly shouldn't involve massive string creation.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Indeed, that was my point.  But if the current approach is (for example) pulling rows out into objects in memory, then trying to manipulate them before saving to file...

Comment: If you're putting this stuff into a file and then reading it out using a binary read, then beware: What character encoding are you using? What languages do you need to support? Things can get hairy in some cases (chinese support using UTF8, for example).

Comment: I am using Oracle database, don't know the specific version... So, the best option would be to add these characters in the SQL, or I unterstood wrong?

@MatthewWatson I don't need localization. I believe that UTF is used

Comment: As an alternative, you could start with an existing file containing whitespaces only (with the required line length). When you write the file, just override existing whitespaces. No idea if this is faster then PadRight, but as always, benchmark both with real conditions and choose the best. IMO padding in the SQL query is the best option though.